# Uninitialized Constant when using Gem to share models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, rubygems

I keep getting the 'Uninitialized Constant' error when trying to view pages on my app, this happens since bundling my models into a gem and sharing my database between two apps..its like the models are not being loaded?

So my app routes to 'pages#index and here is the controller

```
 class PagesController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @portfolios = Portfolio.all
 end

 end
```

Nice and simple. So the error message i get is

```
uninitialized constant PagesController::Portfolio
```

Im my database.yml file i have pointed the app to the second apps development database

```
database: myblog_development
```

I am loading my models in the gem like so, #blogModels.rb file

```
require "blogModels/version"

module BlogModels

 Gem.find_files("models/*.rb").each do |f| 
 filename = File.basename(f, '.*')
 class_name_symbol = filename.classify.to_sym
 autoload class_name_symbol, "models/#{filename}"
end

end
```

my gem structure

```
-blogModels
  -lib
    -blogModels
      -version.rb
    -models
      -portfolio.rb
      -sector.rb
  -blogModels.rb
```

and my Portfolio model is setup like this in my gem

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

has_many :portfolio_sectors
has_many :sectors, through: :portfolio_sectors
has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
attr_accessible :overview, :title, :url, :sector_ids, :image_id, :images_attributes

#Validations
validates :title, :presence => {:message => 'Add your Title'}
validates :url, :presence => {:message => 'Add a URL'}
validates :overview, :presence => {:message => 'Add an Overview'}
validates :sector_ids, :presence => {:message => 'Choose At Least 1 Sector'}


def previous_post
 self.class.first(:conditions => ["title < ?", title], :order => "title desc")
end

 def next_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title > ?", title], :order => "title asc")
 end

end
```

Im not sure how else to debug this so if anyone has any pointers then please advise. I am confused as to why this would not work.

Comment: what is the `Portfolio`?

Comment: Portfolio is a model for which an index and show action are contained

Comment: it seems that the either the `Portfoilo` model has an other name, or simple hasn't loaded that is strange

Comment: must be not loading as names are identical... but cant figure out why the gem is not loading them

Comment: had the `Portfolio` constant defined in a gem?

Comment: yes i have a portfolio.rb model setup in the gem

Comment: how did you set the portfolio u[ in the gem?

Comment: ill add it to the question

Comment: @majioa ive added my model setup

Comment: have you loaded `lib/model` as a folder? for example, on load app, exactly on loading that controller do: `require 'model/portfolio'`

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the your gem is in the Gemfile and that you've restarted the server
2. You need to require the file that contains the model
3. If you're still facing issues, check if `::Portfolio` works for you
4. As a rule of thumb, when you move models (or classes in general) into a gem, place them in a namespace module and reference your class by `MyGemName::Portfolio`

Edit:

Since you're sharing your models among different projects, it would make sense to have the models grouped in a module

```
module MyAwesomeModels
  class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
    # self.table_name = 'portfolios' # if you face issues accessing the tables, this might help
  end
end
```

Comment: could you provide an example of the namespace module you are referring to please, just for clarity

Comment: I added the 'set_table_name' line just in case you end up needing it. I'm not sure if activerecord would figure out the table name if it's in a module =) (I think it would but just in case =))

Comment: thanks for the help here, does my path look correct to you to call the models?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. You're the one who's going to be using the gem and you know best. Here's an example for a model `Delayed::Job` https://github.com/zxiest/delayed_job_active_record_threaded/blob/master/lib/delayed/job.rb ; I suggest you open your console and do some tests :-)

Comment: wondering if you could help again..im trying to run my Gem.find_files script in the console to ensure the files are being found, they are to a point, how can i execute the whole script in the console?  Gem.find_files("models/*.rb") returns an array of paths, 1 path is "/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myblogView/bundler/gems/blogModels-1c051ca11f6d/lib/models/portfolio_sector.rb"  I want to check that the rest of the script is working correctly

Comment: Have you tried including your gem in the project's Gemfile using  the path option? `gem 'mygem', '0.0.4', :path => '/projects/mygem'` ; you should consider doing unit tests on your (project) code and making sure you cover everywhere you're using the gem. Trying to load the files separately is not what you should be aiming for in the project where you're using the gem especially if you've tested the gem.